# How to generate particles from the center of my window? (qml)

Tags: qt, qml, particles

I am working with the **particle system** in *qml*, but I want my particles *originating from the center of my rectangle.*

The foregoing I can tell you that it is already done, but what I do not like is that *the particles emerge in disorder and without direction.*
I would like the particles to spread evenly from the center to the ends, but I do not know how to do it.
If someone I could suggest some idea.
I annex my code.

Corrections, ideas or suggestions that solve my problem are accepted.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys
    }

    Emitter{
        id: emitter
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 14; width: 16
        system: particleSys
        emitRate: 80
        lifeSpan: 4000
        lifeSpanVariation: 500
        maximumEmitted: 1000
        size: 5
        endSize: 40           

        velocity: TargetDirection{     
            targetX: 0; targetY: 0
            targetVariation: 360
            magnitude: 250
        }
    }

    ImageParticle{
        source: "images/blueBlip.png"      //My image
        system: particleSys
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, make the code runnable (add imports, remove dependency on the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the person who asked the question.
I found a solution to my question.

To emit ordered particles you can make use of the *burst()* **method**.

This event allows us to emit a certain number of particles from our emitter. You can manipulate it according to what you need.

I implemented it through a Timmer:

```
Timer{
    interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
    onTriggered: particles.burst(particles.emitRate)
}
```

The code would look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys
    }

    Emitter{
        id: particles
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 14; width: 16
        system: particleSys
        emitRate: 80
        lifeSpan: 4000
        lifeSpanVariation: 500
        maximumEmitted: 1000
        size: 5
        endSize: 40           

        velocity: TargetDirection{     
            targetX: 0; targetY: 0
            targetVariation: 360
            magnitude: 250
        }

        Timer{
              interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
              onTriggered: particles.burst(particles.emitRate)
        }
    }

    ImageParticle{
        source: "images/blueBlip.png"      //My image
        system: particleSys
    }
}
```

If someone knows a more efficient way or someone can improve it ... contribute your answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this!

You don’t need a timer though! You only need to call particles.burst() once to get it started. Calling it every half a second could slow things down; instead you should set the Emitter start time to 0.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Rectangle {
id: bg
width: 360
height: 360
color: "black"

   ParticleSystem {
       id: particleSys
   }

   Emitter{
       id: particles

       startTime: 0

       anchors.centerIn: parent
       height: 14; width: 16
       system: particleSys
       emitRate: 80
       lifeSpan: 4000
       lifeSpanVariation: 500
       maximumEmitted: 1000
       size: 5
       endSize: 40           

       velocity: TargetDirection{     
           targetX: 0; targetY: 0
           targetVariation: 360
           magnitude: 250
        }
    }

    ImageParticle {
        source: "images/blueBlip.png"      //My image
        system: particleSys
    }
}
```

Or you could call particles.burst() on a specific event such as Component.onCompleted:

```
      Emitter{
      id: particles
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      height: 14; width: 16
      system: particleSys
      emitRate: 80
      lifeSpan: 4000
      lifeSpanVariation: 500
      maximumEmitted: 1000
      size: 80
      endSize: 100

      velocity: TargetDirection{
          targetX: 0; targetY: 0
          targetVariation: 360
          magnitude: 250
      }

      Component.onCompleted: {
          particles.burst(particles.emitRate)
      }
  }
```